# Problem with xRDP on Ubuntu 18.04 (parse_vt_settings)

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

1. I tryied to install xRDP on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS following various methods.
2. When trying from  a MS-Win10 machine I got the following connection error problem:

[image]

The **.xorgxrdp.10.log** file look like this:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[687588.293] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[687588.293] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-168-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[687588.293] Current Operating System: Linux galois 5.3.0-7629-generic #31~1581628854~18.04~2db8a7a~dev-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 14 19:57:43  x86_64
[687588.293] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-7629-generic root=UUID=28534b53-7964-409d-aa4e-5677f2344235 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
[687588.293] Build Date: 14 November 2019  06:20:00PM
[687588.293] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
[687588.293] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[687588.293]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
[687588.293] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[687588.293] (++) Log file: ".xorgxrdp.10.log", Time: Tue Mar 10 10:37:08 2020
[687588.294] (++) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xrdp/xorg.conf"
[687588.294] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[687588.294] (==) ServerLayout "X11 Server"
[687588.294] (**) |-->Screen "Screen (xrdpdev)" (0)
[687588.294] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor"
[687588.295] (**) |   |-->Device "Video Card (xrdpdev)"
[687588.295] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "System76 nVidia Card"
[687588.295] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Video Card (xrdpdev)"
[687588.295] (**) |-->Input Device "xrdpMouse"
[687588.295] (**) |-->Input Device "xrdpKeyboard"
[687588.295] (**) Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
[687588.295] (**) Option "AutoAddDevices" "off"
[687588.295] (**) Not automatically adding devices
[687588.295] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[687588.295] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[687588.295] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[687588.295] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[687588.295] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[687588.295]    Entry deleted from font path.
[687588.295] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[687588.295]    Entry deleted from font path.
[687588.295] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[687588.295]    Entry deleted from font path.
[687588.295] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[687588.295]    Entry deleted from font path.
[687588.295] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[687588.295]    Entry deleted from font path.
[687588.295] (==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
        built-ins
[687588.295] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[687588.295] (II) Loader magic: 0x5580189dd020
[687588.295] (II) Module ABI versions:
[687588.295]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[687588.295]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[687588.295]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[687588.295]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[687588.299] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c10
[687588.302] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[687588.302] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/dri/card0: Operation not permitted
[687588.303] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[687588.303] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/dri/card1: Operation not permitted
[687588.303] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card2)
[687588.304] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to take device /dev/dri/card2: Operation not permitted
[687588.326] (--) PCI:*(0:2:0:0) 10de:103c:10de:1095 rev 161, Mem @ 0xc4000000/16777216, 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xc0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00006000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[687588.326] (--) PCI: (0:3:0:0) 10de:1024:10de:0983 rev 161, Mem @ 0xc6000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432
[687588.326] (--) PCI: (0:129:0:0) 10de:1b00:10de:119a rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000f000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[687588.326] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[687588.326] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[687588.326] (II) Module "dbe" already built-in
[687588.326] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[687588.326] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[687588.326] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[687588.326] (II) Module "extmod" already built-in
[687588.326] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[687588.327] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[687588.328] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.328]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.328]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[687588.328] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[687588.328] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[687588.328] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.328]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.328]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.328] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[687588.328] (II) Module "record" already built-in
[687588.328] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[687588.328] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[687588.328] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.328]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.1.0
[687588.328]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.328] (II) LoadModule: "xorgxrdp"
[687588.328] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libxorgxrdp.so
[687588.328] (II) Module XORGXRDP: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.328]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.328]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.328] xorgxrdpSetup:
[687588.328] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[687588.329] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[687588.329] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.329]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.329]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[687588.329] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpdev"
[687588.329] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.so
[687588.329] (II) Module XRDPDEV: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.329]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.329]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.329] xrdpdevSetup:
[687588.329] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[687588.329] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[687588.329] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[687588.329] (II) Unloading nvidia
[687588.329] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[687588.329] (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
[687588.329] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[687588.329] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[687588.329] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[687588.329] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[687588.329] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[687588.329] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[687588.330] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.330]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.0.15
[687588.330]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[687588.330]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.330] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[687588.330] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[687588.330] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[687588.330] (II) Unloading nvidia
[687588.330] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[687588.330] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpdev"
[687588.330] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/xrdpdev_drv.so
[687588.330] (II) Module XRDPDEV: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.330]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.330]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.330] xrdpdevSetup:
[687588.330] (II) UnloadModule: "xrdpdev"
[687588.330] (II) Unloading xrdpdev
[687588.330] (II) Failed to load module "xrdpdev" (already loaded, 0)
[687588.330] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[687588.330] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[687588.330] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.330]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[687588.330]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[687588.330]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.330] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[687588.330] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[687588.330] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.330]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[687588.330]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[687588.330]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.330] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[687588.331] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[687588.331] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.331]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[687588.331]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[687588.331]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[687588.331] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpmouse"
[687588.331] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpmouse_drv.so
[687588.331] (II) Module XRDPMOUSE: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.331]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.331]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[687588.331]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[687588.331] rdpmousePlug:
[687588.331] (II) LoadModule: "xrdpkeyb"
[687588.331] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/xrdpkeyb_drv.so
[687588.331] (II) Module XRDPKEYB: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[687588.331]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[687588.331]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[687588.331]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[687588.331] rdpkeybPlug:
[687588.331] rdpIdentify:
[687588.331] (II) XRDPDEV: driver for xrdp: XRDPDEV
[687588.331] rdpDriverFunc: op 10
[687588.331] (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Fri Apr 21 14:41:17 2017 -0400
[687588.331] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
[687588.331]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
[687588.331]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
[687588.331]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
[687588.331]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
[687588.331]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
[687588.331]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
[687588.331]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
[687588.331]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
[687588.331]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
[687588.331]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
[687588.331]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
[687588.331]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
[687588.331]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
[687588.331] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[687588.331] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[687588.331] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[687588.331] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[687588.331] (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
[687588.331] (EE)
[687588.331] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[687588.331] (EE) Please also check the log file at ".xorgxrdp.10.log" for additional information.
[687588.331] (EE)
[687588.331] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor
[687588.332] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor
[687588.332] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

**Please what is going wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the `xorgxrdp` package is installed. If not, install it with:

```
sudo apt install xorgxrdp
```